# JavaScript if statement from select box

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, html-select

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong - when "Europe" is selected nothing happens.

When I take away the if statement it works, so the output code is definitely okay. The problem seems to be with the if condition.

```
 <script> 

 function shipping_calc() {  
    var val = document.getElementById.("country").value;    
    if(val === "Europe") {   
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "£2.40";
    }   
 }

</script>

<select id="country" onchange="shipping_calc()">
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
  <option value="Worldwide">Worldwide</option>
</select>

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: You have document.getElementById.("country") (notice the period before ("country")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an extra `.` in your javascript. This works.

```js
function shipping_calc() {

  var val = document.getElementById("country").value;

  if (val === "Europe") {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "£2.40";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="country" onchange="shipping_calc()">
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
  <option value="Worldwide">Worldwide</option>
</select>

<p id="output"></p>
```

---

You had `document.getElementById.("country")` and it should have been `document.getElementById("country")`.

Comment: Of course it had to be something so simple. God dammit. Just takes a fresh set of eyes I guess. Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var vall = document.getElementById("country");
var val = vall.options[vall.selectedIndex].value;

if (val === "Europe") {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "£2.40";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6dvgbjr0/

You had an error in your code, with an extra period:

```
var val = document.getElementById.("country").value;
```